# What is the result of the double use of the new int?

Tags: c++, arrays

I've searched far and wide and I cannot work out what this produces. I've seen no other examples where "new int [] is used twice within one array. Can anyone help?

```
    int *t [2] = { new int [2], new int [2] };
```

Answer (score 5):

`t` is an array of two `int*`, which are, generically, pointers to `int`.

The `new` operator is allocating an array of 2 consecutive `int` on the heap, by returning a memory address to that allocated memory (`int*`). This is done twice, thus allocating two arrays and storing them in the outer array.

Answer (score 3):

Since `new int [2]` gives you a heap-allocated array of two integers (each time you call it), you'll end up with an array `t` of integer pointers pointing to distinct arrays of integers, something like this:

```
(array) (points to) (arrays-on-heap)
t: [0]      ->      [int0, int1]
   [1]      ->      [int2, int3]
```

---

Were you to print out `&t`, `&(t[0])` and `&(t[1])`, you would find that was an array with the first two items the same and the third slightly higher (the size of an `int *`). This is because array elements are consecutively placed.

Printing out `t[0]` and `t[1]` *may* have wildly disparate values since they can come from anywhere on the heap. They probably *won't* be that different simply because consecutive heap allocations tend to be done from consecutive memory<sup>(a)</sup>, but they're likely to be separated by *some* memory - this is because many common allocation strategies involve allocating blocks of a minimum size/resolution, and with inline control information *between* blocks.

Printing out `&(t[0][0])` and `&(t[0][1])` will again give you close values since they form part of an array.

Note that those paragraphs above are not all *mandated* to be true by the standard, they're just the most common scenarios. It's possible that allocation strategies may involve exact sizes and out-of-line control information, but it would be unlikely.

---

<sup>(a)</sup> There may be exceptions to this in optimised allocators if, for example, different-sized requests come from different pools, or there's a separate preferred pool per thread. But, in the general case here, that's unlikely.

Comment: "It's possible that an array of int values may have 64 bytes padding between each element": are you sure? As far as I know, in C and C++ there can be no padding between array elements. How would array indexing and pointer arithmetic work in that case? `sizeof(T[N])` should always be `N * sizeof(T)`.

Comment: That's a good point, @Fabio, it looks like intra-array padding would break the `&(a[1]) == &(a[0]) + 1` rule. Have updated answer to suit.